# matplotlibで描画した散布図に線形回帰直線を追加する方法

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlibで，x,yというデータをもとに散布図を描画したのですが，このグラフに線形回帰直線を追加する方法を教えてください．回帰直線の傾きも表示したいです．
よろしくお願いします．

ソースコードを以下に記します．

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
x=dataframe["100"]
y=dataframe["200"]
fig=plt.figure()
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.5,color="Blue",linewidths="1")
plt.clf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpyでフィッティング直線を計算させます。
seabornとCSVを読み込みは行なっていませんが、サンプルコードとしてはこんな感じでしょうか？
近似式の表示追加しました。ax.text()で傾きaと切片bを表示させてください。サンプルの表示位置はなんとなくです。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
# フィッティング直線
y2 = a * x + b

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.5,color="Blue",linewidths="1")
ax.plot(x, y2,color='black')
ax.text(0.1,a*0.1+b, 'y='+ str(round(a,4)) +'x+'+str(round(b,4)))
plt.show()
```

jupyter notebookでの結果
   [image: jupyter notebookでの結果]

Comment: 傾きを表示するにはどうしたらいいですか？

Comment: 回答に傾きの表示の仕方を追記しました。